# Change color of specific parts of an image onclick of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I have is an image of many balls, that are randomly placed in it.
I want to have some buttons, that represent colors, and when you click on the buttons, then the balls change color, depending on what you chose.
The balls will be divided on three categories, that always change to the same color, and you will be able to choose from 10 different colors.
For example if I have 9 balls, balls 1,3,5 , 2,4,9 and 8,7,6 will get the first, second and third color(button) chosen. But those balls are not the one next to the other, they are on different parts of the image.
I've searched a lot but I couldn't find a method to do that. Is there a way? Do I have to use multiple images, or something else? I can't think of anything.

Comment: You can use SVG and manipulate it with Javascript.

Comment: Need more description. An image cannot be edited using javascript or CSS. If you are using a jpg or png it is impossible. There might be ways to manipulate using javascript though if it is an svg image.

Comment: I have a personal project and what I want to achieve is similar to what happens at this MnM's page,but using color or/and text changes
https://www.mymms.com/configurator.do?customerType=B2C . Do I need to edit my question too?I don't know if I can use their site as a reference

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

it's better that each ball is HTML element(div or something).
You can set background image and each ball will be html element.

Then you can set events that handle the clicks on the balls.
For example:

```
$('.ball-green').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ball-green').addClass('ball-red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use multiple images with different ids to each image.

Depending upon the click of a button, you will grab the ids of images that you want and change the background image of each ball that you want to change.